# Generate excel report using jqgrid and coldfusion

Tags: jquery, excel, jqgrid, coldfusion

Does anyone have a tutorial or code samples on how to implement report generating with jqgrid and coldfusion.

I added a button to my grid but not sure how to process data any further. Excel report must be in new window popup.

Basically, my question is, can I capture the data from the grid itself or, do I take arguments from the grid and generate report on new coldfusion page using the same query as I use to generate the grid?

Thank you in advance.

Gena

```
).navButtonAdd('#pager',{caption:"To Excel", onClickButton:
            function(){
                    document.location.href=''  // call processing file
            },
            position:"last", title:'Export to Excel' }
        );
```

Comment: Another approach is to offer the user a choice of how he wants his output before he makes his page request.

Comment: By the way, document.location.href is not how you call the popup.  You want window.open().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to have your button call a new page that generates the Excel file. In the new page, re-run your query and then output to an HTML table with a content type of `application/vnd.ms-excel` or use `<CFSPREADSHEET>` to generate the Excel file from the new page.

Comment: `output to an HTML table with a content type of application/vnd.ms-excel` since this isn't actually an Excel document, just an html document, using it where an Excel formatted file is required can cause an error.  if you were to upload that file and read it with cfspreadsheet CF would throw an input binary stream error.

Comment: Regarding "re-running the query", this might be a suitable situation for caching it in the first place.